# Disable/enable entire form's submit with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

When my form doesn't validate, I want to disable the form's submit function.
I can do this by disabling the submit button, but this would leave the enter key unchecked.
I can set the .submit(return false); but then I can't re-enable it again later.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just a simplification of Pim's (edited to pull up James contribution):

```
$('#form').submit(formValidated);
```

Answer (score 10):

I did the following, which worked (disable submit button and form submit):

```
var condition = true; //check whatever you like
if(condition)
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('form').bind('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();});
}else{
    $('input[type=submit]', this).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('form').unbind('submit');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

How about doing the check inside the submit method:

```
$('#form').submit (function() {
 if(formValidated())
  return true;
 return false;
});
```

Comment: Just a note you probably already knew about: Don't forget to also make your validations on the server-side though because having javascript disabled will bypass this.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simplification of Nick's **original** answer:

```
$('#form').submit(formValidated);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible solution:

```
$('#form').change(function() {
    (isValid($('#form')) ? $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled',false) : $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled',true)
});
```

Of course, `isValid()` checks that all your `$('#form')` elements comply to your validation rules. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only piece of code that works for me.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // or return false;
});
```

Comment: Try to elaborate a bit more and explain why it works, but good job! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly calling the submit function call an intermediary function and do a check in there.

i.e.

```
var isSubmitable = false;

function submitForm() {
   if(isSubmitable) {
       myform.submit();
   }
}
```